Nextjs API Integration is not working, error 404
Really suffering here and I do not know wherelse to go. I have been for days trying to integrate my local nextjs 14 app to the strapi API, but no matter what I always get a 404 error, and in the frontend console:
_utils/axiosClient.jsx
const { default: axios } = require("axios");

const apikey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REST_API_KEY;
const apiUrl = "http://localhost:1337/api";

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: apiUrl,
    headers:{
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apikey}`,
    }
});


export default axiosClient;

_utils/halakatApis.jsx
const { default: axiosClient } = require("./axiosClient");

const getLatestHalakat = () => axiosClient.get("/halakas?populate=*");
const getHalakaById = (id) => axiosClient.get(`/halakas/${id}?populate=*`)

export default {
    getLatestHalakat,
    getHalakaById
}

halaka-details/[halakasId]/page.js
"use client";

import halakatApis from "@/app/_utils/halakatApis";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function halakaDetails({Promise}) {

  useEffect(() => {
    getHalakaById_();
  },[Promise?.halakasId]);

  const getHalakaById_=() => {
    halakatApis.getHalakaById(Promise?.halakasId).then(res => {
      console.log('halaka item',res.data.data);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>{Promise?.halakasId}</div>
  )
}

export default halakaDetails

'http://localhost:1337/api/halakas'
{
"data": [
{
"id": 2,
"documentId": "pkwk6m6ombegof18v7st24wi",
"startTime": "15:00:00.000",
"endTime": "17:00:00.000",
"studentNo": 19,
"halakaKind": "ذكور",
"createdAt": "2024-12-01T19:58:02.378Z",
"updatedAt": "2024-12-01T19:58:02.378Z",
"publishedAt": "2024-12-01T19:58:02.386Z"
},
{
"id": 4,
"documentId": "e6v44rdgxl9mmau79qvsjh1i",
"startTime": "09:00:00.000",
"endTime": "11:00:00.000",
"studentNo": 12,
"halakaKind": "ذكور",
"createdAt": "2024-12-01T19:58:52.011Z",
"updatedAt": "2024-12-01T19:58:52.011Z",
"publishedAt": "2024-12-01T19:58:52.016Z"
}
],
"meta": {
"pagination": {
"page": 1,
"pageSize": 25,
"pageCount": 1,
"total": 2
}
}
}

The console should have appeared in 'halaka', res.data.data

If you are using Strapi v5, then documentId should be used instead of id. See here
documentId instead of id in v5
Your api call would look like this :
/halakas/${documentId}?populate=*


Thank you for replying, I tried this method but I have the same problem error: 404                 const getHalakaById = (documentId) => axiosClient.get(/halakas/${documentId}?populate=*);  AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404

I took a closer look and realized that the way you are trying to access Promise?.halakasId will not work directly in your useEffect dependency array. Promise is not typically how data is passed to a React component. You need to use useParams from next/navigation
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
const { halakasId } = useParams();

Also use console and browser Network to see if you are getting halakasId. Hope you find it helpful
